# R: Convert N*M data.frame (or data.table) to (N*m)*3 data.frame

Tags: r, format, dataframe, data.table

I am using the data.table package to read (fread) bigger files from disk. The read data.table looks like

```
   C1,  C2,   C3
R1 0.5, 0.9,  0.1
R2 0.7, 0.1,  0,1
R3 0.2, 0.3,  0,5
```

But, for scanning issues, I would like to have them in the form of:

```
R1, C1, 0.5
R1, C2, 0.9
R1, C3, 0.1
R2, C1, 0.7
```

So, is there an efficient way to do that? When using rbind, cbind, etc. this takes forever.
The files I am reading are having ~500k rows ~100 columns.

Best regards,

Mario

Comment: `help("melt.data.table")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep lines if needed:

Starting with dataframe:

```
dt = data.frame(c1=c(0.5,0.7,0.2), c2=c(0.9,0.1,0.3), c3=c(0.1,0.1,0.5))
row.names(dt) = c("R1","R2","R3")
melt(as.matrix(dt))
```

Starting with data.table, you cant only get rowlines:

```
dt = data.frame(c1=c(0.5,0.7,0.2), c2=c(0.9,0.1,0.3), c3=c(0.1,0.1,0.5))
melt(as.matrix(dt))
```

Comment: Melt was the right hint, thanks. Didn't know about that.

Comment: Strangely, though this answer has been upvoted and accepted, it doesn't make sense--`data.table`s don't have `rownames`, so the `as.matrix` is just going to slow things down....

Comment: It would make sense if they had read the data as a `data.frame` though.

Comment: I didn't use this code, I just took melt and melt.data.table as starting point.

Comment: I understood he wanted to keep line numbers in his data.table
My answer makes sense since you cant track lines number after a single melt ...
I edited it for dataframes since you seems peecky :)

Comment: @mariodeng, `melt` is the most logical candidate--I was just pointing out that the answer didn't make sense in the context of your using `fread` to get your data in. However, your question does show something that appears to be like row names. You might need to clarify in your question what your data actually look like--perhaps with the output of `dput(head(whatever-you-read-in))`. Colonel--sorry that the checkmark was removed--it wasn't my intention! Just pushing you for a better answer :-)